# How to use saveTOCassandra()

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark, spark-streaming, rdd

I am new to spark I want to save my spark data to cassandra with a condition that I have an RDD and I want to save data of this RDD into more he one table in cassandra?Is this possible if yes then how ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Spark-Cassandra Connector.

How to save data to cassandra: example from the docs:

```
val collection = sc.parallelize(Seq(("cat", 30), ("fox", 40)))
collection.saveToCassandra("test", "words", SomeColumns("word", "count"))
```

See the project and full documentation here: https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector

Comment: I have seen this link but in my case  i want to save "cat" to table "words1" and "fox" to table "words2 " and both "cat" and "fox" are the part of same collection then what to do?

Comment: You should be more specific in the question then. May I suggest you to ask a new question with the specific issue and sample code that illustrates it?

Answer (score 1):

Python pyspark Cassandra saveToCassandra Spark

Imagine your table is the  following:

```
CREATE TABLE ks.test (
  id uuid,
  sampleId text,
  validated boolean,
  cell text,
  gene text,
  state varchar,
  data bigint, PRIMARY KEY (id, sampleId) );
```

---

How you can update only the 'validated' field for a given sampleId in the test table in the keyspace ks ? You can use the following line to update the table in Python.

---

```
from pyspark import SparkConf

import pyspark_cassandra

from pyspark_cassandra import CassandraSparkContext

conf = SparkConf().set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", <IP1>).set("spark.cassandra.connection.native.port",<IP2>)

sparkContext = CassandraSparkContext(conf = conf)

rdd = sparkContext.parallelize([{"validated":False, "sampleId":"323112121", "id":"121224235-11e5-9023-23789786ess" }])

rdd.saveToCassandra("ks", "test", {"validated", "sample_id", "id"} )
```

Comment: @maasg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52928181/why-cassandra-tablewriter-writing-0-records-and-how-to-fix-it